# Datasource Paging Issue

Tags: google-app-maker

A simple setup: department: employee, 1:M and a search form that filters on FirstName =, lastname =, email contains, age >=, join date <= and related department = .

A submit button will then open up a results page with the datasource set to the appropriate search method. I have direct filtering where we bind to @datasource,query.filters.FirstName_equals, etc. I have a datasource based on a query buillder solution and a third solution based on a query script. A appropriate search results page opens on Submit and the datasource of the results page is set to the appropriate datasource: filter, query builder or query script.

The solution that uses a query script and a results page based on this datasource is as follows:-

query script

```
var params = query.parameters;

return getEmployeeRecords_( 
  params.param_FirstName, 
  params.param_LastName, 
  params.param_Email, 
  params.param_StartDate, 
  params.param_Age, 
  params.param_Department
);
```

and

```
function getEmployeeRecords_( firstName, lastName, email, startDate, age, 
    department) {

 var ds = app.models.Employee.newQuery();

 if ( firstName )
    ds.filters.FirstName._equals = firstName;

  if ( lastName ) 
    ds.filters.LastName._equals = lastName;

  if ( email ) 
    ds.filters.Email._contains = email;

  if ( startDate )
    ds.filters.StartDate._greaterThanOrEquals = startDate;

  if ( age )
    ds.filters.Age._lessThanOrEquals = parseInt(age, 10);

  if ( department )
    ds.filters.Department.Department._equals = department;

  var records = ds.run();

  var recs = records.length;

  // update calculated model with record count
  var calculatedModelRecords = [];
  var calculatedModelRecord = app.models.Employee_RecordCount.newRecord();
  calculatedModelRecord.RecordCount = recs;
  calculatedModelRecords.push(calculatedModelRecord);

  return records;
}
```

On the results page for the query script datasource paging is just broken. A query that correctly returns 8 records where the query page size is set to 5 allows me to get the pager to go to page 1000 if I wished, but the datasource always stays on the first page of records. With page size set to e.g., 100 the correct result set is clearly displayed. The direct binding and query builder datasources work as expected.

The reason for doing these different searches is as a test and evaluate each option, and also to be able to return a record count, which I can only do with a query script.

Anyone any ideas as to the cause of this aberrant App Maker behaviour ?

Also when I query the calculated model Employee_RecordCount to retrieve the record count using a UI label with text of "Number of Records: " + @datasources.Employee_RecordCount.item.RecordCount this shows null.

What's the best way to retrieve the record count using the calculated model Employee_RecordCount?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your actual code omits the {} with each if statement or if you just didn't include them in your question. However, see my proposed changes to your code below:

```
function getEmployeeRecords_( firstName, lastName, email, startDate, age, department) {

 var ds = app.models.Employee.newQuery();

 if ( firstName !== null ) {
    ds.filters.FirstName._equals = firstName;
 }
 if ( lastName !== null ) {
    ds.filters.LastName._equals = lastName;
 }
 if ( email !== null) {
    ds.filters.Email._contains = email;
 }
 if ( startDate !== null) {
    ds.filters.StartDate._greaterThanOrEquals = startDate;
 }
 if ( age !== null) {
    ds.filters.Age._lessThanOrEquals = parseInt(age, 10);
 }
 if ( department !== null) {
    ds.filters.Department.Department._equals = department;
 }
 var records = ds.run();

 var recs = records.length;

 // update calculated model with record count
 var calculatedModelRecord = app.models.Employee_RecordCount.newRecord();
 calculatedModelRecord.RecordCount = recs;

 return [calculatedModelRecord];
}
```

As for the paging issue, for some reason AM has always had that problem with calculated models. There may be a bug report filed in their AM issue tracker.

Comment: Just implemented your code suggestion and unfortunately no difference I'm afraid.

Comment: @SilverFox Ok, I guess maybe let me clear up some things. Your query script is located in the Server Script section of your calculated model right? How are you passing your params to the calculated model, is it via a field binding or do you run a client script that passes your filters from your actual datasource to your calculated model?

Comment: The query script works and retrieves the correct set of records. But just to clarify, the Employee query is a cloud SQL model. But as I said, the paging is up the creek. It displays the first page but when I click on the pager next page it refreshes and shows the next page number but always displays the first page of records. I can go to page 1,000 even if there are only 8 records retrieved and a page size of 5.

Comment: My reference to a calculated datasource was the Employee_RecordCount datasource, which is a calculated model for storing the count of records returned. No paging as there should only be one record.

Comment: The issue with the Employee_RecordCount calc model is retrieving the data. If I put this in the query script function

    var rs = app.models.Employee_RecordCount.newQuery().run();
    var i = rs.length;
    console.log(i);

The whole query doesn't even display records.

I'm tempted to zip up the project and ask the G-Suite team to pass it to the App  Maker team and let them sort it out.

What I want is a simple solution to a stupidly simple problem: how to retrieve a count of records for a query. It to me is SO dumb that they haven't implemented this functionality.

Comment: @SilverFox The paging for calculated models never functioned before as I mentioned. It has to do with some type of bug, although the the documentation suggests that it should work.

Comment: @SilverFox In regards to querying a calculated model, that is actually not possible because you are creating the records on the fly vs them being stored anywhere. So even though you may just have 'created' some records in a calculated model you would not be able to query them without repopulating the entire record set and applying the filter in the function that creates the calculated model records.

Comment: Markus, the paging issue isn't to do with a calculated model it's a cloud SQL model. There is reference to a calc model Employee_RecordCount within the function for the purpose of storing a count of records. The paging issue is to do with a returned record set from a query based on any of firstname, lastname, email, age, start date and related department.

Comment: @SilverFox Ok, so what you are saying is that you are running your record count function from inside the query script that belongs to your Employee Model datasource?

Comment: Markus just to clarify - cloud SQL model with binding like these
@datasources.Search_Query_Script.query.parameters.param_Age

Then the values are referenced in the datasource query script where I write

return getEmployeeRecords_( 
  params.param_FirstName, 
  params.param_LastName, 
  params.param_Email, 
  params.param_StartDate, 
  params.param_Age, 
  params.param_Department
);
getEmployeeRecords is a server script in a script modulde. The values are passed correctly and the query works insofar as it retrievs the correct results. But the paging doesn't work.

Comment: The calc model for storing record count is another separate issue. I just can't seem to be able to retrieve the result. If I query the calc model from within the getEmployyRecords script it goes into a stack overflow or the query doesn't display anything. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @SilverFox It sounds like the paging and the inability to retrieve your record count issues go together though. I think the paging issue may be related to your binding on the nextPage()/previousPage() buttons on your datasource, especially if you incorporate your total record count from the calculated model and that result is returning null to your client, so your paging buttons enabled property is not correctly picking that up and therefore you are able to go up to 1000 pages.

Comment: @SilverFox With that being said, I have this scenario working in my own application. It does however require to be set up in a very specific manner. I am willing to share this setup, but don't have the time right now. It would need to be later.

Comment: @SilverFox Also, please star the issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63892969, which I created especially because of this shortfall in App Maker. I use total record counts from queries all over my application, and for each instance it takes just about 40 lines of code both on client side and server side to pass my datasource filters to the calculated model that is supposed to return a count of all records that fit those filters. It's annoying.

Comment: Markus, forget about the calc model. if I remove that bit of code form the getEmployeeRecords function I'm left with a paging issue as described. I'm not doing anything specific with the bindings on the prev/next page. The results page has the server query datasource as datasource and I dropped in a table based on this datasource.